# How to create a custom arrow head

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

There is a long list of options for arrow heads. Unfortunately, the one I need is not among them. I couldn't find a way to create one. However, there is this element for lost messages in the SysML-library:

[image]

[image]

It does have a custom arrow head named "sysMLLost":

[image]

I would like to create my own. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Bumping. I too would like to know how to do this.